# Adding pairs of numbers in a list

Tags: python

I am new to programming. I am currently learning python and I am trying to add pairs of numbers in a list. Let's say I have something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6]
```

and I am trying to add them in pairs like this:

```
a = [1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 + 6]
```

Also, the list will always have an even number of elements.I can't wrap my mind around the problem. Please Help.

Comment: What if the input array/list is has odd number of elements?

Comment: ``[x + y for x,y in zip(a[1::2] , a[0::2])]``

Comment: `it = iter(a); [x+y for x,y in zip(it,it)]`